# Strange behaviour in gnuplot for label with Arial font face in pdfcairo terminal

Tags: gnuplot

I am obtaining a strange behaviour on `gnuplot 5.2.2 pdfcairo` terminal with a label composed of several lines and attempted to be printed align to center. The label is the signature for my plots, it is composed of my name (first line), my institution (second line) and the date, obtained from `time(0)` and `strftime`.

In a multiplot script I noticed that the date (3rd line) was printed align to left while the other two line were printed align to center as intended. Then I placed the `set label` instruction before the first plot was called so that the label is printed two times. Then, in the first call, date was aligned to left but in the second call the date was aligned to center, as intended. Same happens if the align to right mode is intended. However if the `strftime` string is substituted by a regular string `"foo"` then alignment works fine.

This behaviour only happens if font is set to Arial and if the terminal is set to `pdfcairo`. If font is set to Ubuntu (or Times) or if the terminal is set to `pngcairo` then all calls print the label truly align to center.

A minimal workable example is:

```
set terminal pdfcairo enhanced color font "Arial," 
set output "prueba.pdf"

set multiplot layout 1,2 

set colors podo
Cadena_firma="Martin-Olalla JM\nUniversidad de Sevilla\n".strftime("%Y/%m/%d",time(0))
set label 1 at screen 0.85,0.25 Cadena_firma noenhanced center font "Arial,10" tc rgb '#9d2235' front
set yrange [-2:2]
plot sin(x) lc 3


plot cos(x) lc 3
```

I attached the output, highlighting the weird printing of the date.

This is only happening in one of the computers I handle. It is easily solvable by changing the font. Nonetheless I am curious and it might be interesting for others. [image: Output of the minimal workable example, highlighting the placement of the date in the first call of the label]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There have been multiple reports of font problems that all appear to trace back to bad pango/cairo library versions.  Some of the problems are OS-specific and some are font-specific.  So there are probably multiple issues involved.  Here are some tracker items:
    https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/pango/issues/422
and
    https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/2052/